# <springProperty> in logback-spring.xml not working with externalized application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I have my spring boot application.properties loaded from file system with @PropertySource on my @Configuration class.

If I want to use application properties in my logback-spring.xml with `<springProperty>` tag, it is not working.

But if I place the application.properties in the classpath under src/main/resources, the `<springProperty>` tag works.

Any idea why it is not working with externalized application.properties loaded with @PropertySource annotation ?

Comment: I found out the reason on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: Could you share the exact reason ?

Comment: The logging system is initialized early in the application lifecycle and as such logging properties will not be found in property files loaded via @PropertySource annotations.